# gtkmm & glade - multiple window not working

Tags: c++, glade, gtkmm

using gtkmm.h header file, I created a simple app with glade template. Signal works fine but I am trying to change window or open another window on click event signal. member function fires but another window is not opening. If i create different Gtk::Application::create() then also 2nd window open after closing 1st one. Does anyone have any idea about this.?
Anything can be helpful.

`GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:45:21.107: g_application_parse_command_line: assertion '!application->priv->options_parsed' failed`

and this is the error that shows in terminal.

event after creating different instances for Application and Builder below error shows up and 2nd window still fails.

`Failed to register: An object is already exported for the interface org.gtk.Application at /org/gtk/Application/anonymous`

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of your code to show the issue.

Comment: @BryanH I have submitted answer but I got another issue explained along answer. Do you have any thoughts about it. anything is helpfull. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `childWindow->show();`

but still there is one issue how to add widget like Gtk::Label into Gtk::Window or Gtk::Box when window is build using glade.
I added by creating but shows no error nor label. I did something like below:-

```
Gtk::Label test;
test.set_label("Hello");
gtkBox->add(test);
```

Does anyone have any idea about this..?